# MySQL: I want to sum my employees cost and group it by employee and by day

Tags: mysql, date, group-by, sum

I currently have a table where I record all my employee daily expenses

```
John Smith    01 JAN 2010    200$ 
John Smith    01 JAN 2010    50$
John Smith    01 JAN 2010    10$
Lady Gaga     01 JAN 2010    50$ 
Lady Gaga     01 JAN 2010    20$
John Smith    02 JAN 2010    10$
```

What I would like to display a table that contains a daily report of all bills:

```
01 JAN 2010
John Smith: 260$
Lady Gaga: 70$

02 JAN 2010
John Smith: 10$
```

I really hope my request is understandable and you will be able to help me.

Thank a lot for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a standard group-by:

```
select date, name, sum(amount) as total
from mytable
group by 1,2
order by 1,2;
```

Answer (score 1):

use [SUM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) with GROUP BY , do something like

```
SELECT date,user,SUM(cost)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY  date,user
ORDER BY  date
```